Use a drop down filter when some fields contain multiple values
I am using Google Looker to create a report that lists content from a website.  I want the users of the report to be able to filter the content by topic.  However, some content is tagged to multiple topics. (Separated by commas in the field)
I've resolved this by using the Advanced filter with "Contains" but this has the drawback of not providing the users with a discrete list of terms they can filter for.
The values are not always in the field in the same order and can be combined with any other value.
What is the best way to address this?
I've tried to use a CASE formula to create a new field but it categorizes it based on the first one it sees.
I've also looked to see if I can create a clean dropdown list of terms that then pre-populates the advanced filter for "Contains" or works in a similar way but I have had no luck.
Thanks in advance.
